# Get list of list of objects from linq query

Tags: c#, linq, list

Is there any way to query a list of objects, group them and then output them as their own list as a list of lists?  I don't know how to explain it so I'll show you.

```
public class Note
{
    string CreatorID;
    string Title;
    string Text;
}
```

I have a populated list of notes (`List<Note> noteList`).  There are multiple creators and multiple notes for each creator.  I'm trying to figure out if there's a way using a LINQ query to group the notes by CreatorID then, separate them and output them as a list of list of notes (`List<List<Note>> creatorsNotes`).  This way I can loop through creatorsNotes to get creators and their list of notes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest would be to use [`ToLookup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549073%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var groups = noteList.ToLookup(n => n.CreatorID);

foreach(var group in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Items with CreatorID {0}", group.Key);
    foreach(var item in group)
          Console.WriteLine("   Title: {0}", item.Title);
}
```

You could also use `GroupBy` if needed.  Note that these will not directly create a `List<List<Note>>`, however.  If that is required, you could do:

```
List<List<Note>> grouped = noteList.GroupBy(n => n.CreatorID)
                                   .Select(g => g.ToList()) 
                                   .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you both for the responses.  Reed's GroupBy gave me exactly what I wanted with least amount of headache.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, let's let `list` be the `List<Note>`:

```
var creatorNotes = list
    .GroupBy(note => note.CreatorID)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        g.CreatorID,
        Notes = g.ToList()
    })
    .ToList();
```

As pointed out by Reed, this is a list of an anonymous type that indicates the grouped `CreatorID` at the root as well as the `Notes` associated with that `CreatorID`.

Comment: That will make a List of an anononymous type containing the key + a list.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, right, so that the OP is capable of knowing what the group is. I guess it's another way of going about the lookup strategy you also provided.